# Taking more than 3 minutes to update a Firestore document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

A simple update in a Firebase document from a Firebase function (using Firebase admin) is taking more than 3 minutes!

1. The update is instantaneous using Firebase emulator
2. The Firestore database has no more than 20 entries in total
3. The delay happens even in subsequential requests in the same minute (doesn't seem to be a "cold start" issue)

```
const userData = {
   firstName: "John",
   lastName: "Doe"
}

/***** FROM HERE *****/
functions.logger.log("Updating user", userData)

const usersRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc("1")
usersRef.set(userData, { merge: true })
        .then(() => {
              /***** TAKES 3 MINUTES TO GET HERE *****/
              functions.logger.log("Success user updated!", userData)
          })
        .catch((error) => {
              functions.logger.error("Error updating user!", error)
          })
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the complete function as it is? You should also add a `return` before the `set()`

Comment: In addition to what Dharmaraj asked, can you also show how you measured the timing? Even if that's just through some `console.log` statements, please include those statements and their output in the question, so we can see precisely where the time is going.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'm getting the timing from Firebase Console -> Functions -> Logs: 

10:54:16.810 am
addUser
Request completed.
10:54:17.111 am
addUser
Updating user
10:57:35.009 am
addUser
Success user updated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, getting the reference is asyncronous and you are not handling that.

```
const userData = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
}

functions.logger.log('Updating user', userData)

admin
  .firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc('1')
  .then((usersRef) => {
    usersRef
      .set(userData, { merge: true })
      .then(() => {
        /***** TAKES 3 MINUTES TO GET HERE *****/
        functions.logger.log('Success user updated!', userData)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        functions.logger.error('Error updating user!', error)
      })
  })
```

The cleaner (and more reliable) version of this code would be to use async/await and not promise chaining

```
const cleanFunction = async () => {
  const userData = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
  }

  functions.logger.log('Updating user', userData)

  try {
    const usersRef = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('1')
    await usersRef.set(userData, { merge: true })
    functions.logger.log('Success user updated!', userData)
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error('Error updating user!', error)
  }
}
cleanFunction()
```

Comment: Thanks so much @omeanwell . Regarding your first suggestion, .doc() doesn't return a promise, so I couldn't use then().

However, I've used your async suggestions, and it seems to fix the problem! What is really odd to me is that my initial update block is exactly what's described on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data (Web version 8).

The code I've initially shared happens inside a Firestore onCreate trigger. So I've moved the update block outside the trigger and the delay is gone.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No worries! Thats very strange, but glad it works :D Nice one